# Increment CSV File everytime a new Form is Submintted

Tags: php, csv

Im trying to increment just a plane number when something in the Form is send, in my CSV File.

Adding File works, so when First name is submitted the first name is shown in the .csv File.

Here is my doc Root.

```
 $this->flatFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Storage/contacts.csv';
```

Here is my add Function.

```
public function add(ContentDto $contentDto)
{


    $contact = [
        count($this->flatFile),
        $this->addNextNumber(),
        $contentDto->getGender(),
        $contentDto->getFirstName(),
        $contentDto->getLastName(),
        $contentDto->getEmail(),
        $contentDto->getText(),
        $contentDto->getPhoneNumber()
    ];

    $fp = fopen($this->flatFile, 'a+');
    fputcsv($fp, $contact);
    fclose($fp);

}
```

Where `$this->addNextNumber()` There is my increment function...which is empty. Which is why im here.

Thank you in Advance.

Edit:

Example...
Now: `,0,Tomas,Müller,email@email.com,"some text from Tomas",123-123-321` ( Note 0 is Gender )

Want:

```
1,0,Tomas,Müller,email@email.com,"some text from Tomas",123-123-321 (Note 0 is Gender)
2,0,Tomas,Müller,email@email.com,"some text from Tomas",123-123-321 (Note 0 is Gender)
3,0,Tomas,Müller,email@email.com,"some text from Tomas",123-123-321 (Note 0 is Gender)
```

Edit: My Trys.

```
 private function addNextNumber()
{

    First Try.
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("Model/contacts.csv", "a+")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<p> $num Felder in Zeile $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }


    Second Try.
    $fp = fopen($this->flatFile, 'a+');
    $fp++;
    return $fp;


    Third Try.
    $d = $this->flatFile;

    for ($n=0; $n<10; $n++) {
        echo ++$d . PHP_EOL;
    }


    Forth Try.
    $number = $this->flatFile;
    $number++;
    echo  $number;

}
```

Comment: Short: Everytime a new Form is submitted add++. So everytime 'Send' Is pressed the Data is filled and the first number is incremented. Not sure how else to explain it. My englisch is not the best :(

Comment: I did try lots of stuff, but none worked. Edited. Keep in mind, im a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Trial and Error this worked for me.

```
    $row = 0;
    if (($handle = fopen("Storage/contacts.csv", "a+")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<p> Zeile $row <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);

    }
    return $row;
```